# Entry visa to Bolivia for a Romanian citizen

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, bolivia, romanian-citizens

I had a look on Romanian Foreign Affairs Ministry page and they say that Romanians do need visa for entring in Bolivia.

Unfortunately, Bolivia does not have an embassy in Romania, the Ministry says that one can go to Berlin or Vienna to get it, an option which I don't like too much.

Also [here](https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php?p1=ro&fl=&s=yes) says that I need visa. On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Bolivia) says that all European Union citizens don't need it with except of 4 countries (mine being one of them, of course).

I found out that one can get the visa on arrival but for a fee, if you get it before it is free.

I will pass through Argentina and Chile before going to Bolivia so my plan is to get it from the Bolivian Embassy in Buenos Aires or Santiago. Is it possible?

Also about Chile, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_of_Bolivia) says that

> Due to strained relations with Chile, Bolivia only has
>   Consulates-General in Chile.

Are they able to give an entry visa in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've found [here](https://haihuistory.com/2018/07/29/south-america-in-2-5-months-all-you-have-to-know-to-do-it-yourself/) which is the procedure for it:

- passport
- 2” x 2” passport-type photo
- yellow fever vaccination certificate
- bank statement
- travel itinerary (we printed a map with our itinerary)
- proof of stay in Bolivia (we booked a refundable night in a hostel in La Paz, got the email confirmation, then cancelled it)
- proof of entering Bolivia (we copied the information of a private tour Atacama – Uyuni, without purchasing anything in advance)
- proof of leaving Bolivia (we copied the information of a bus company with the La Paz – Titicaca – Copacabana – Puno route, without purchasing anything in advance)

With everything stated above, go the the following site and register your application [here](https://portalmre.rree.gob.bo/formvisas/).

At the end of the online process, you will get a Statement for Visa Application. With this printed Statement and the hard copies of everything you prepared, you will go to the Consulate. At the Bolivian Consulate in Buenos Aires, we got out with the Visa after 40 minutes.

You can do all the preparation before your departure, so that when you arrive to the Consulate you have all your papers ready.

**PS:**

This part was written after I got the visa. The hard copies and photos are not needed. I had them but they said they are already saved in my visa application. I got the visa from Bolivian Consulate in Buenos Aires, Argentina. Could be different in other locations.