# Can I transit Bolivia, by bus, if I don't have visa?

Tags: visas, buses, visa-free-entry, bolivia, romanian-citizens

I can *not* enter Bolivia without a visa.

I have a Romanian Passport (European Union) and I am wondering if I can travel directly from Brazil to Peru (a direct bus leaving from Sao Paulo to Lima), using my passport, without a visa.

Is a visa required to transit Bolivia by bus?

Is it similar to the airports where I don't need a visa if I don't leave the neutral area of the airport, entering the country? Or do I need a visa for a bus ride?

Comment: Have you checked whether or not Romanians can get visas on arrival at the border? Might be an easy option.

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica As far as I know that’s not possible.

Comment: Yep. Looks like it's possible tho online: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122768/entry-visa-to-bolivia-for-a-romanian-citizen?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have entered Bolivia twice by bus from Chile, and left once by bus (to Peru).

Every time at the border (once it opened), every single passenger was required to disembark and go through immigration.

One possible reason is that they have rest breaks and multiple stops as well, meaning if you were trying to 'sneak' into Bolivia, you'd have a chance.  Therefore, everyone is checked. You'd need a visa.

Comment: That’s what I was thinking. You cannot easily jump out of an airplane while flying, but you can leave the bus during the lunch stop. However, when I went from Brazil to Uruguay, the bus company took our passports, and during the night we crossed the border and when I woke up in Uruguay I had the stamps on my passport. I didn’t have to interact with the immigration office. But yes, I guess I would need a visa...